# Being unable to request migration from some questions to a different exchange site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There was a recent question posted on Stackoverflow [PHP MySQL code optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352887/php-mysql-code-optimize)

though, being some-what valid on SO. A question like this would be best suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).. But whilst attempting to close I was presented with:

[image] along with the standard serverfault migration notice which is located on the previous section. So, would it not be a good thing to allow the choice of any of the exchange sites? By using a list or a text box to specify the site?